# Exclude logged in cross domain tracked users

Tags: google-analytics

We have a CMS and a SAAS application, one is on .co.uk and the app is on .com

we have set up cross domain tracking in google analytics, so we can see the users interaction on both domains. What we want to be able to do in google analytics is exclude users that are a logged in.

it feels like we just need to add a custom variable to the gtag code in the head, but I can't find anything that feels like the correct way to do this. lots of articles talk about excluding based on a /login url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find documentation on how to add custom dimensions and metrics with gtag.js: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets

You have to manage the code based on login (only when user is logged). Set the custom dimension with `hit` scope.

Then you can create a report applying a segment to exclude interactions or sessions that contain that dimension.